# Serialization is returning each character as object

Tags: python, django, django-serializer

I have a simple view, in which I need to return JSON data but when using `django serialize` and `JsonResponse` it returns each character as an object. Here is the snippet:

```
def query(request):
    data = serializers.serialize('json', Post.objects.all())
    response = JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
    return response
```

The problem is that if I want to print `response.content[0]` it returns some random number as it's the first character of the response.

Is there any way I can make the response to be accessed like a simple dictionary (JSON)?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have a JSON, it's basically a `string` - so you can not access it like a dictionary/list or any Python type.

If you need to access it like a dictionary or a list, you should operate on the non serialized data:

```
def query(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()

    print(posts[0]) # You can now use it as a list of objects

    data = serializers.serialize('json', posts)
    response = JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
    return response
```

Comment: I actually need to access it from Javascript as an Object. If I use the returned list I just get the `__str__`. I'm trying to get the entire `Post` so I can use it when displaying the interface.

Comment: @Rod Well then you need to show us your js code as well.. Also try to console.log the returned content in response callback.